# Magento 2 installation display blank page

Tags: magento2, installation

1. step 1-> magento2 download from https://github.com/magento/magento2
   version 0.1.0-alpha101all
2. step 2-> install composer globally using
       composer windows installer.
3. step 3-> run composer install in
           magento2/setup directory using CMD and everything is installed
           perfect.

Then, I went to localhost/magento2/ .. the browser is redirected to a new url localhost/magento2/setup/ with title "Magento Setup Tool" but a blank page is displayed. No install steps are displayed in my browser. I tried that with firefox and chrome with same results.

Its a common situation?, anyone knows if we have to erase some file after we run composer install into setup directory?

server error.log: [Sat Oct 25 16:19:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/magento2/setup/controls, referer: localhost/magento2/setup/

Comment: What do your server logs say?

Comment: [Sat Oct 25 16:19:07 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Zend/Apache2/htdocs/magento2/setup/controls, referer: http://localhost/magento2/setup/

Comment: I dont have a folder named setup/controls , installation using composer did not generate that folder. but i dont know where i can find a complete installation to compare what is missing.. all files were downloaded from github official mangento2 account. brgds

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an alpha release of Magento 2 and no longer relevant

Comment: @fschmengler you are right. i will delete. thanks. brgds

Comment: @fschmengler I cannot deleted because it has answers. moderator must delete it. brgds.

Comment: @s_h I think, closing it enough: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/907/magento-2-questions-tagged-beta-alpha-pre-alpha-etc-quo-vadis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try with dev beta (or the most recent build). There was quite a bit of change in the installer in weeks before dev beta. The web setup may have been broken in that alpha build - it is working now in beta1 at least.

There are a number of posts around now talking about how to get dev beta up and going. Examples include a video linked from http://magento.com/developers/magento2 but quite a few people have blogged on this now - find your favorite with Google if you don't like the video.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a vhost instead of the default localhost/magento setup. It seems your installation is looking for some files in the root directory of your hard drive and i dont think that is correct.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/706 it seems that the installer is not complete. thank you anyway @mbalparda